# QFileDialog not allowing the parent window to update

Tags: qt

I'm trying to get a QFileDialog to select a directory. But, when the dialog is open, the parent window won't update. It does that thing where it keeps an image of any other window that's dragged across it, and won't redraw until I close the dialog.

The following code is in a slot in my main window, connected to a QPushButton's "clicked" signal:

```
QFileDialog dlog(this);
int result;

... set dialog to directories only ...

result = dlog.exec();

if (result == QDialog::Accepted) {
    ... blah blah blah ...
}
```

It doesn't really affect the functionality at all, because the user can't interact with the window while the dialog is open anyway. It's just an annoying visual glitch.

This is in QT 5.11. Right now I'm developing on Linux, but this application will eventually be ported to Windows, so a solution that works for both OSs would be appreciated.

[image]

Edit 2: A minimal, verifiable, and complete example is below. This code creates a window with a single button. Clicking the button opens the file dialog. While the dialog is open, dragging any window across the main window causes the goofiness shown in the above screenshot. Closing the dialog causes the main window to refresh like nothing happened.

mainwindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void handleclick();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(this);
    QObject::connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(handleclick()));
}

void MainWindow::handleclick()
{
    QFileDialog dlog(this);

    dlog.exec();
}
```

The main.cpp file was auto-generated by QTCreator, but, for the sake of completeness, here it is anyway:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You could show an image of the problem you have.

Comment: eyllanesc -- Nope, I'm still a newbie, and I don't have enough reputation to post images. Sorry.

Comment: upload it to https://imgur.com/, share the link and I'll put it in your question

Comment: Would Dropbox work? (Don't have an imgur account). [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yjleiklag1ymhq/cuteissue.png?dl=0) The window to the left (with the blacked-out title) is my main window. To the right is the QFileDialog.

Comment: what is your distro?

Comment: Fedora Core. (LXDE desktop, if that matters.)

Comment: Is that I work in Arch Linux with gnome and I do not see that *nice "windows" effect*, you could provide a [mcve] to rule out that the code you use generates that problem.

Comment: I've added an example to the original post.